# Como abrir nova Activity ao clicar no elemento filho em ExpandableListView?

Tags: java, android

Gostaria de saber se é possível abrir uma nova Activity ao clicar num elemento filho de uma `ExpandableListView`, tendo em mente que, para cada elemento de item filho abra um Activity especifico?

Meu layout consiste em uma Tablayout com Lista Expansível então, gostaria de saber, como fazer nesse esquema de layout onde usa fragments.

Segue meu projeto

Código Java=Package/Telas/adaptador

> Classe Adaptador

```
package com.marcos.programador.projetobus.Telas;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.marcos.programador.projetobus.Cursos;
import com.marcos.programador.projetobus.R;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Marcos on 23/02/2017.
 */

class Adaptador extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private List<String> listaGrupos;
    private HashMap<String, List<Cursos>> listaItensGrupos;
    private Context context;

    public Adaptador(Context context, List<String> grupos, HashMap<String, List<Cursos>> itensGrupos) {
        this.context = context;
        listaGrupos = grupos;
        listaItensGrupos = itensGrupos;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return listaGrupos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int grupoPosicao)
    {
        return listaItensGrupos.get(getGroup(grupoPosicao)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int grupoPsicao)
    {
        return listaGrupos.get(grupoPsicao);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int grupoPosicao, int inicioPosicao)
    {
        return listaItensGrupos.get(getGroup(grupoPosicao)).get(inicioPosicao);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int grupoPosicao)
    {
        return grupoPosicao;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int grupoPosicao, int inicioPosicao)
    {
        return inicioPosicao;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds()
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int grupoPosicao, boolean isExpanded, View converteVisualizacao, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(converteVisualizacao == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            converteVisualizacao = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grupo, null);
        }
        TextView tvGrupo = (TextView) converteVisualizacao.findViewById(R.id.tvGrupo);
        TextView tvQtde = (TextView) converteVisualizacao.findViewById(R.id.tvQtde);
        tvGrupo.setText((String)getGroup(grupoPosicao));
        tvQtde.setText(String.valueOf(getChildrenCount(grupoPosicao)));
        return converteVisualizacao;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int grupoPosicao, int inicioPosicao, boolean finalPosicao, View converteVisualizacao, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(converteVisualizacao == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            converteVisualizacao = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_grupo,null);
        }
        TextView tvItem = (TextView) converteVisualizacao.findViewById(R.id.tvItem);
        TextView tvValor = (TextView) converteVisualizacao.findViewById(R.id.tvValor);
        Cursos cursos = (Cursos) getChild(grupoPosicao,inicioPosicao);
        tvItem.setText(cursos.getNome());
        tvValor.setText(String.valueOf(cursos.getValor()));
        return converteVisualizacao;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int grupoPosicao, int inicioPosicao)
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

> Classe Dados

```
package com.marcos.programador.projetobus.Telas;

import com.marcos.programador.projetobus.Cursos;
import com.marcos.programador.projetobus.MainActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Marcos on 23/02/2017.
 */

public class Dados extends MainActivity {

    static List<String> listaGrupos = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<Cursos> listaItem1 = new ArrayList<Cursos>();
    static List<Cursos> listaItem2 = new ArrayList<Cursos>();
    static List<Cursos> listaItem3 = new ArrayList<Cursos>();
    static HashMap<String, List<Cursos>> listaItensGrupo = new HashMap<>();
    public  static List<String> carregaGrupo(String nome){
        listaGrupos.add(nome);
        return listaGrupos;
    }

    public static List<Cursos> carregaItem1(String nome, Double numero){
        listaItem1.add(new Cursos(nome, numero));
        return listaItem1;
    }

    public static List<Cursos> carregaItem2(String nome, Double numero){
        listaItem2.add(new Cursos(nome, numero));
        return listaItem2;
    }

    public static List<Cursos> carregaItem3(String nome, Double numero){
        listaItem3.add(new Cursos(nome, numero));
        return listaItem3;
    }

    public static HashMap<String, List<Cursos>> carregaRelacionamentos(){
        listaItensGrupo.put(listaGrupos.get(0), listaItem1);
        listaItensGrupo.put(listaGrupos.get(1), listaItem2);
        listaItensGrupo.put(listaGrupos.get(2), listaItem3);
        return listaItensGrupo;
    }
}
```

> Classe tela2

```
package com.marcos.programador.projetobus.Telas;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

import com.marcos.programador.projetobus.R;


/**
 * Created by Marcos on 28/02/2017.
 */

public class tela2 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    ExpandableListView lista;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    public static tela2 novaInstancia() {return  new tela2();}
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View tela=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tela2,null);
        inicializaObjetos(tela);
        carregaLista();
        return tela;
    }
    // Inicializando Objetos
    private void  inicializaObjetos(View tela)
    {
        lista=(ExpandableListView) tela.findViewById(R.id.listaCursos);
    }
    //Carrega Lista
    private void carregaLista()
    {
        //Criando os grupos
        Dados.carregaGrupo("Android Studio");
        Dados.carregaGrupo("Java Netbeans");
        Dados.carregaGrupo("PHP");

        //Criando os itens do grupo Android Studio
        Dados.carregaItem1("Manhã", 0.0);
        Dados.carregaItem1("Tarde", 0.0);
        Dados.carregaItem1("Noite", 0.0);

        //Criando os itens do grupo Java Netbeans
        Dados.carregaItem2("Manhã", 0.0);
        Dados.carregaItem2("Tarde", 0.0);
        Dados.carregaItem2("Noite", 0.0);

        //Criando os itens do grupo PHP
        Dados.carregaItem3("Manhã", 0.0);
        Dados.carregaItem3("Tarde", 0.0);
        Dados.carregaItem3("Noite", 0.0);

        //Criando Relacionamento dos grupos com seus itens
        Dados.carregaRelacionamentos();

        // Criando um adaptador com os dados acima
        Adaptador adaptador = new Adaptador(getActivity(), Dados.listaGrupos, Dados.listaItensGrupo);
        //adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, armazena);

        //Definindo o adaptador
        lista.setAdapter(adaptador);

    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){ return "Horarios";}

}
```

> classe MainActivity

```
package com.marcos.programador.projetobus;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.marcos.programador.projetobus.Adaptador.QuadroAdaptador;
import com.marcos.programador.projetobus.Telas.tela1;
import com.marcos.programador.projetobus.Telas.tela2;
import com.marcos.programador.projetobus.Telas.tela3;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
    private TabLayout Guias;
    private ViewPager abreTela;
    int atualPosicao=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.Ferramenta);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //Abre páginas da guia
        abreTela = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.Paginas);
        carregaPaginas();
        //Configuração Guia
        Guias = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.Guias);
        Guias.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        Guias.setupWithViewPager(abreTela);
        Guias.addOnTabSelectedListener(this);
    }

    //Preencher páginas
    private void carregaPaginas()
    {
        QuadroAdaptador quadro=new QuadroAdaptador(getSupportFragmentManager());
        quadro.addPage(tela1.novaInstancia());
        quadro.addPage(tela2.novaInstancia());
        quadro.addPage(tela3.novaInstancia());
        abreTela.setAdapter(quadro);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        abreTela.setCurrentItem(atualPosicao=tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
}
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.marcos.programador.projetobus.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            android:id="@+id/Ferramenta">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/Guias"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/Paginas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> grupo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.marcos.programador.projetobus.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            android:id="@+id/Ferramenta">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/Guias"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/Paginas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> item_grupo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvItem"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:text="Item"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvValor"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="Valor"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
</LinearLayout>
```

> tela2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/listaCursos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Você já tentou alguma coisa?

Comment: Veja [ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener.html)

Comment: como assim? Não entendi, mais eu não tetei utilizar o onitemclicklistener como sou iniciante não entendi como usa-lo pois o exemplo que eu achei não utiliza Tablayout.

Comment: Olá ramaral tudo bom? Eu não entendi como utilizá-lo como especifiquei logo acima sou iniciante  ainda não utilizei esse comando.

Comment: alguma solução??

Comment: Ola gostaria de dar o tópico como encerrado pois já encontrei outra maneira de fazer o que precisava agradeço a todos

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa setar um listener na ExpandableListView. Crie um listener na sua expandableListView:

```
mListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_list);
mListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

        switch(childPosition){

            case 0:
               //TODO Faça sua chamada da activity aqui

            break;

            case 1:
                //TODO Faça sua chamada da activity aqui

            break;


        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Valeu Rafael Lucena vó tentar

Comment: Ola Rafael Lucena tudo bom? Bem tetei acionar o listener mais o android studio reconheci como um código invalido e da erro

Comment: Você pode colocar o seu código aqui ? Para dar uma noção.